# Wait until event is fired

Tags: c#, winforms

After asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65299355/wait-for-variable-change-value-in-while-loop-thread?noredirect=1#comment115444555_65299355), I am wondering if it is possible to wait for an event to be fired.

My application is always look for request from *application1*.
If has request from *application1*, get request information and send message many times to *application2*.

But I must do it in synchronization way. If I send message 3 times, send first message, wait for first message response, send second message, wait for second response, send third message and wait for third response. And between times I have to wait for about 10s so I use `Thread.Sleep(10000)`.

I currently after send message I will wait with `AutoResetEvent.WaitOne()` before sending second message. And if I receive message from the outside application I will inform with `AutoResetEvent.Set()`.

Please see my code and give me anything not good or give me advice. Thank you very much.

```cs
AutoResetEvent res = new AutoResetEvent(false);

private bool blnHasRequest;
private void FormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new Thread(new ThreadStart(new ThreadStart(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            //check request form application 1
            if (blnHasRequest)
            {
                int intExcuteTimes = 3;

                //Send message to application 2 and wait for reponse
                for (int i = 0; i < intExcuteTimes; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Send message " + i);
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting reponse " + i);
                    res.WaitOne();
                    Console.WriteLine("Received response " + i);
                    Thread.Sleep(10000);
                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }))).Start();
}

//Fired from application2
private void OnReceivedResponse(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    res.Set();
}
```

Comment: Are you really talking about "applications"? You do mean that one windows application should talk to another windows application? Or do you mean different objects within one Application should talk to each other?

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse Yes. Applications. My application communicate with Application 1 through database and communicate with Application 2 through Window Message.

Comment: Do you want to run some code when some value changed?

Comment: @Muaath I am sorry I don't understand your question clearly. I will process data in `OnReceivedResponse` and finally `res.Set()`. And in the loop, no, just send the message.